# Django - Extend page doesn't fill

Tags: python, django

I want to fill my index.html with content of the header.html.

The index.html shows everything - except the content of the header.html. Why isn't it showing the "Hello World"?

On the header.html I also tried to ref to "index.html" or "Immo/private/index.html", but it didn't worked.

[image: project structure]

header.html:

```
{% extends 'private/index.html' %}

{% block content %}
<h1>fill: Hello World</h1>
{% endblock %}
```

index.html:

```
{% load static %}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
        <title>Index-Page</title>
    </head>
<body>
    <div class="page-header">
        <h1><a href="/">Index-Page</a></h1>
    </div>
    <div class="content container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-8">
                    {% block content %}
                    {% endblock %}
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

settings.py:

```
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))
TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates/')],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]
```

I work with django 2.1 on Visual Studio on windows.

Comment: Are you by any chance rendering `index.html` in your views? In that case your template inheritance needs to be the other way around

Comment: You are right. I changed it, then I got an "TemplateDoesNotExist" error and changed the code to "{% extends 'Immo/private/index.html' %}". Thank you for your help :)